# Creating dynamic masks based on mask value list using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I wonder how to create a dynamic mask from a list of values. At the moment, I have it hardcoded as follows:

```
mask = (
    clipped.neq(10)
    .And(clipped.neq(80))
    .And(clipped.neq(50))
    .And(clipped.neq(70))
    .And(clipped.neq(90))
    .And(clipped.neq(95))
    .And(clipped.neq(100))
    .selfMask()
)
```

However, I want the mask to be dynamically created based on a mask_values list. For example: mask_values = [10, 80, 50, 70, 90, 95, 100]

Answer (score 1):

You can interatively add property to your mask:

```py
mask = clipped
for v in mask_values:
    mask = mask.And(clipped.neq(v))
mask = mask.selfMask()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works great.

Answer (score 1):

This will produce a 1 if any pixels match any values in the list.  If you want it to be a 0 if any occur, then just `.not()` the result.

```
var mask = clipped.eq([10, 80, 50, 70, 90, 95, 100]).reduce(ee.Reducer.max())
```

The input list of values are automatically turned into a multiband image, and the input image is compared to each of those bands, producing a multiband image of 0/1s.  The `reduce` then gets the max over all bands.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I am not sure how to apply .not() in python. "mask = clipped.eq([10, 80, 50, 70, 90, 95, 100]).reduce(ee.Reducer.max()).not()" doesn't work in terms of syntax

Comment: I think you can simply use "neq" instead

Comment: In Python `not` is a reserved keyword, so it's `.Not()` (capitalized).  You could use `neq()` but you want to know that all are false, so you need to use `max().eq(0)`